# Replace Visual Studio's native debugging DataTip in VS extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

A few days ago I've started to play around with the creation of VS-extensions and their possibilities.

How is it possible to either extend or replace the DataTip which is displayed while hovering over an object in the debugging mode?

I'm currently struggling to find a way to "hook" into the event where the user is hovering over the variable and the datatip gets created. I know that [custom visualizers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx) can be used to create a forms/WPF-window to display the object, but these are only displayed after clicking on the magnifying glass icon within the DataTip itself.

It's possible to configurate the DataTip with a [natvis configuration file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx) for specific types, but that's too limited. In the end I want to hook into the event and instead of displaying the native DataTip, I want to display my own WPF-window (which would be filled via reflection of the hovered object).

Do I have to use a specific MEF component such as the IQuickInfoSourceProvider which is used to create a custom QuickInfo?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JDB I think the question is quite specific.

Comment: The ExtendVS Gitter room has the right people to ask, and is very active: https://gitter.im/Microsoft/extendvs

Comment: @JDB: I've updated the question a little bit to show where my current problem is.

Comment: @Govert Thank you for the link, I've never heard of it before!

Comment: Hey, did you found any solution for this?

Comment: I have the same project. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I found a solution : using GlobalCbtHook (https://github.com/arlm/Global-CbtHook), i can intercept the creation of the window and close it before it appears.